# ¿Por qué vuelve a llamar a la función si ya he obtenido resultado con el 'return'? undefined en DOM

Tags: javascript, funciones

buenos días! A ver si me podéis ayudar. Me he encallado un poco en este punto y no consigo salir del atolladero. El ejercicio trata de elegir un número hasta acertarlo.

Una vez acertado, debería salir el mensaje del else (ahí retorna el mensaje), el cual sí sale haciendo debugger, pero sale *undefined* (vuelve a llamar a la función).

Adjunto el código aquí abajo. Abierto a cualquier sugerencia en otros aspectos, ya que estoy en fase de aprendizaje.

Un saludo y muchas gracias de antemano ;)

```
let numRandom = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 500);

let numUsuario = () => {
  let numUsuario = Number(prompt(`Indica un número cualquiera entre 1 y 500.`));
  let mensaje = juego(numRandom, numUsuario);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = mensaje;
};


let juego = (nr, nu) => {
  //   let msj = ``;
  let diferencia1 = nr - nu;
  let diferencia2 = nu - nr;

  if (nu <= 0 && nu >= 500) {
    alert(`Error, el número elegido es incorrecto. Vuelva a intentarlo.`);
    numUsuario();
  }

  if (diferencia1 >= 50) {
    alert(`Frío, frío. Tu número es más pequeño (${nu}).`);
  } else if (diferencia2 >= 50) {
    alert(`Frío, frío. Tu número es más grande (${nu}).`);
  } else if (diferencia1 >= 15 && diferencia1 <= 50) {
    alert(`Templado, templado. Tu número es más pequeño (${nu}).`);
  } else if (diferencia2 >= 15 && diferencia2 <= 50) {
    alert(`Templado, templado. Tu número es más grande (${nu}).`);
  } else if (diferencia1 >= 1 && diferencia1 <= 15) {
    alert(`Caliente, caliente. Tu número es más pequeño (${nu}).`);
  } else if (diferencia2 >= 1 && diferencia2 <= 15) {
    alert(`Caliente, caliente. Tu número es más grande (${nu}).`);
  } else {
    let msj = `¡ENHORABUENA, HAS ACERTADO EL NÚMERO! Era el número (${nu}).`;
    return msj;
  }

  numUsuario();

  //  return msj;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tu problema es que el primer llamado a `numUsuario` nunca sale de ahi, porque dentro de `numUsuario` llamas a juego y juego llama `numUsuario`, creando una recursión.
Si por ejemplo, el primer intento y el segundo intento son fallidos y el tercero es correcto, al salir de las funciones el orden será el inverso, entonces al salir del correcto cambiará por el mensaje, pero al salir del segundo ya será `undefined` (porque un intento fallido no devuelve nada) y luego lo mismo con el primero, también es `undefined`.

Lo que puedes hacer para solucionarlo es que solo cambie el mensaje del elemento `demo` si el mensaje contiene algo.

Te dejo el ejemplo con un numero de 1 a 5 para que lo puedas probar.

```js
let numRandom = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5);

let numUsuario = () => {
  let numUsuario = Number(prompt(`Indica un número cualquiera entre 1 y 5.`));
  let mensaje = juego(numRandom, numUsuario);
  if(mensaje) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = mensaje;
  }
};


let juego = (nr, nu) => {
  //   let msj = ``;
  let diferencia1 = nr - nu;
  let diferencia2 = nu - nr;

  if (nu <= 0 && nu >= 500) {
    alert(`Error, el número elegido es incorrecto. Vuelva a intentarlo.`);
    numUsuario();
  }

  if (diferencia1 >= 50) {
    alert(`Frío, frío. Tu número es más pequeño (${nu}).`);
  } else if (diferencia2 >= 50) {
    alert(`Frío, frío. Tu número es más grande (${nu}).`);
  } else if (diferencia1 >= 15 && diferencia1 <= 50) {
    alert(`Templado, templado. Tu número es más pequeño (${nu}).`);
  } else if (diferencia2 >= 15 && diferencia2 <= 50) {
    alert(`Templado, templado. Tu número es más grande (${nu}).`);
  } else if (diferencia1 >= 1 && diferencia1 <= 15) {
    alert(`Caliente, caliente. Tu número es más pequeño (${nu}).`);
  } else if (diferencia2 >= 1 && diferencia2 <= 15) {
    alert(`Caliente, caliente. Tu número es más grande (${nu}).`);
  } else {
    let msj = `¡ENHORABUENA, HAS ACERTADO EL NÚMERO! Era el número (${nu}).`;
    return msj;
  }

  numUsuario();

  //  return msj;
};

numUsuario();
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta Pipe, me ha servido de mucho. Ahora sí me funciona correctamente. Un saludo!